# Jquery .length .size Count in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

How i can count the total of `<li></li>` ?? I try to .length and .size but I returns it "2" (when 4), thanks !

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  total_notif = $('#notifications li').length;
  //total_notif = $('.data_notifications li').size();
  alert("total :  " + total_notif);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notifications" class="data_notifications">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li> <a href="http://www.vicolinker.net"> Vicolinker 1 </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://www.vicolinker.net"> Vicolinker 2 </a> 
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="menu">
    <li> <a href="http://www.vicolinker.net"> Vicolinker 1 </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://www.vicolinker.net"> Vicolinker 2 </a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

### - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - LONG VERSION --------------------------

JSON:

```
[{
    "module": "demo2",
    "id": 1,
    "icon": "fa fa-hdd",
    "text": "probando noti",
    "link": "www.google.es",
    "datum": "2016-04-04"
}, {
    "module": "demo2",
    "id": 2,
    "icon": "fa fa-happpy",
    "text": "holaa",
    "link": "www.bing.es",
    "datum": "2016-06-12"
}]
```

JS:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        var html = "";
        var total_notifications = 0;
        var json_urls =['./modules/demo2/_notifications.php',
                        './modules/hdd/_notifications.php'];

        for (var i=0; i<json_urls.length; i++){ 

            GetJSONArray(json_urls[i]);
            total_notifications++;
        }

        function GetJSONArray(url){

           $.getJSON(url,function(data){
                //console.log(data);
                var items = [];

                $.each( data, function( key, val ) {

                    items.push('<li> <a href="'+ val.link +'"> <i class="'+ val.icon +' text-aqua"></i>'+ val.text +' </a> </li>' );
                });
              //console.log("HTML OK :    " + items);
            $( "<ul/>", {
                        "class": "menu",
                        html: items.join( "" )
                      }).appendTo( ".datos_notificaciones" );
            });
        }  


     console.log("total: " +total_notifications);

    total_notif = $('#cuenta li').length;
    //total_notif2 = $('.datos_notificaciones li').size();
    total_notif2 = $(".datos_notificaciones ul").children('li').length;
     console.log("total directo :  " + total_notif);
     console.log("total directo2 :  " + total_notif2);
});//]]> 

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="cuenta" class="datos_notificaciones"></div>
```

END HTML:

```
    <div id="cuenta" class="datos_notificaciones">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li> <a href="www.google.es"> <i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i>probando noti </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="www.bing.es"> <i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i>holaa </a> </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="menu">
        <li> <a href="www.google.es"> <i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i>hdd nicht da </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="www.bing.es"> <i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i>adios </a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It is now a little longer but is the same ..... here is where the error comes and does not count the total of `<li>` ...

Comment: it is returning 4 with above code...check https://jsfiddle.net/sxodLb4v/

Comment: `$('#notifications li').length;` did not work ? Do test your code before posting..

Comment: @Rayon i think better close the OP for typo error ?

Comment: @guradio, __This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced__

Comment: @Rayon yes, i test this , but my HTML ist from Json making ... i make long version.

Comment: @VictorMoscosoLembcke do you have multiple div with id "notifications" in page?

Comment: @Jayesh Chitroda not, only one :S

Answer (score 0):

```js
total_notif = $('#notifications li').length;
console.log("total :  " + total_notif);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notifications" class="data_notifications">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li> <a href="http://www.vicolinker.net"> Vicolinker 1 </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://www.vicolinker.net"> Vicolinker 2 </a> 
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="menu">
    <li> <a href="http://www.vicolinker.net"> Vicolinker 1 </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://www.vicolinker.net"> Vicolinker 2 </a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you want to get all the li from all the ul just use the

`$('ul li').length`

Comment: @Rayon i thought `notifications ` is id of ul based on the OP i assumed it was id of ul didnt check the html i jumped the gun but it should work since it is div id

Comment: @guradio  in html i have more ul li ... i need only from this div :/

Comment: @Rayon $('#notifications li').length; give me result "0" :/

Comment: @VictorMoscosoLembcke i updated the question to show that your code should work just fine some other reason is making your code not work made there is an element with the **id** `notifications` which has no LI in it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.length` with a [descendant-selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

```
$("#notifications li").length
```

You can also use [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/), then it's like this:

`$("#notifications ul").children('li').length`

Using only javascript

```
document.querySelectorAll('#notifications li').length
```

Comment: `$('#notifications li').length` should be enough right?

Comment: @guradio yes , it is just to show different options avaiable

Comment: `$('li').length;` return the number of elements

Answer (score 0):

Using [.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) you can get the number of elements in the jQuery object.

```js
var liTotal = $('li').length;
console.log('total :  ' + liTotal);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notifications" class="data_notifications">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li> <a href="http://www.vicolinker.net"> Vicolinker 1 </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://www.vicolinker.net"> Vicolinker 2 </a> 
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="menu">
    <li> <a href="http://www.vicolinker.net"> Vicolinker 1 </a> 
    </li>
    <li> <a href="http://www.vicolinker.net"> Vicolinker 2 </a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```